# Can I take the firefox book marks folder and copy it?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I am trying to create a base ubuntu image with some bookmarks in firefox.  Is there a way I can SCP into the unit and copy\paste a new book marks file?

Thanks!!!

Comment: `scp` into **what** unit? The original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understood u correctly,
Firefox saves Bookmarks, Downloads and Browsing History in the places.sqlite. So you can scp the places.sqlite into the other System with the command below.

```
scp ~/.mozilla/firefox/<source_profile_name>/places.sqlite whoever@example.com:~/.mozilla/firefox/<destination_profile_name>/
```

Or you can just Backup and restore them like described here

[backup and restore bookmarks](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-bookmarks-from-backup-or-move-them#w_backup-and-restore)

Comment: This worked.  I took all the places files and did a cp!